# Why is the onConflict property of the @Insert annotation being used only in one method?

Tags: android, android-room

I was going through Google's documentation about [Accessing data using Room DAOs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data). There's this example about the @Insert annotation:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public void insertUsers(User... users);

    @Insert
    public void insertBothUsers(User user1, User user2);

    @Insert
    public void insertUsersAndFriends(User user, List<User> friends);
}
```

Why is the onConflict property of the @Insert annotation being used just on the first method? Won't any conflicts arise from the other methods?

Or are they simply using the default value (OnConflictStrategy.ABORT) of the onConflict property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you could want different behaviour on a conflict for each insert. If you could only define a single behaviour (per table?, per database?) It would be much less flexible and versatile.

Answer (score 1):

So there are three types [OnConflictStrategry](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy) available + 2 that is already deprecated.

The default one is **ABORT**

- ABORT (Default - Cancel the transaction and changes nothing, rollbacks to the previous data for records that have been updated)
- FAIL (Deprecated)
- IGNORE (Ignores the one with conflict and continue the transaction)
- REPLACE (Remove the previous transaction and add a new record)
- ROLLBACK (deprecated)

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) documentation

And there is something missing in Room that may bother you and that is no **upsert** method.
upsert means insert OR update. The REPLACE doesn't have the same effect as upsert as it removes the record and adds a new one (remove AND insert). If your looking for an upsert this [article](https://tech.bakkenbaeck.com/post/room-insert-update) shows you how to do it.